# ¿Cómo puedo realizar migraciones en producción sin acceso a la consola?

Tags: laravel

¿Cómo puedo hacer migraciones en Laravel si ya estoy en producción pero no tengo acceso al terminal para ejecutarlas?

Comment: No, no tengo :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es un hosting básico u otro servicio en el que solo tengas una conexión FTP, creo que poco puedes hacer, y sobre todo que siga siendo una buena práctica para tu código.
Te aconsejo que de cualquier modo incluyas la migration en tu proyecto, pero tendrás que realizar la consulta sobre la base de datos.